# setting up arguments and source option

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the following command:

```
mysql -u user -pPassword databasename -h server -e "set @yyyymmdd="2015-09-30"; source test.sql";
```

It gives me following error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'source test.sql' at line 1

But if I run the following command, everything works fine:

```
mysql -u user -pPassword databasename -h server -e "source test.sql";
```

I am on "mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.95, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't miss semi-columns for '-e' option

mysql -u user -pPassword databasename -h server -e "set @yyyymmdd='2015-09-30'**;** source test.sql;";

Answer (score 0):

You could do, if you have `sed`:

```
sed -i '1i SET @yyyymmdd="2015-09-30";' test.sql
```

Then

```
mysql -u user -pPassword databasename -h server -e "source test.sql";
```

Comment: Yes @Karthik, i updated my post, seems mysql -e "source xxx" process only batch files

Comment: That worked, but I am still wondering why I am not able to set arguments with '-e' option as they were doing in here : http://databobjr.blogspot.com/2011/07/passing-parameters-to-mysql-query.html.

Comment: Actually, I have missed ';' after source test.sql. After I put ';' my above command works.
mysql -u user -pPassword databasename -h server -e "set @yyyymmdd='2015-09-30'; source test.sql;";